# Is there anyway that this plantuml diagram can be made more comprehensible

Tags: plantuml, c4-model

The below plantuml [code](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/bLJVRze-47_FN-6YxqEGIh-TrBsjKob4PHEiYA1LUq8NSWjU7JkodT9ewly-ds8Q0cahUE5odn-sxyu-ApHaEJ01bIejCpbQa104DyQ2jcKkc7OPBWPeH736vLgKAR8lewl_HrUhaP8EawWl2iVyse7dXP8ehSSdtyRHAbv6Y-X--MiUXVt0F79PW8QSnPMncA-YPyl-1ipzPbm-yDHksAVBorrYWZpRMFRvCdW9Wc6Qrg8bP66lsMRldFqdC4EPBl7PNlVccyhmDGYsGAAmA9xs-gHsQw6M88vTr5PYIZv9Db92wUjU8aeyDFP-zqH-qv7BEjLoAqfTY2C_AXV8wWD3VEump3HMXtOxBVlfKaexms2EsYWPWZ5gpS7YEUiDTx6Jl-u0yqAe2f5jbNOToXYN39YnIkC5-VXctQfIfg2hi2vRP8JpsA-oRsLD3z68xoenZkD0HY5jsK9chdiE6_oXJFz0SGSMjr1vaVzgwpAVR4bXKszdE643samZWGrDYMU_ZkWu2TF4yGjbx23Jw7P2G-RT4YNAcKDlwTylqJZkMj9LcdLTqXZr4ryZ7TvdcF4fNwRc0eHhi21KHWsf8-Rbr2FMhFiwM_sslj1ypINfvtLqebvmYsR32yUUkZ1suOaE6fyuRWsDGnsTg8TDgO6wH_-dhWrSvl28cbRVnSnyvF7orbZljQvElDCvgq4Q0POhwUXB-eBwi_iGxGVdy20cDtI6U1QVeW9hIJLSBjzNlR0W21OeLkFz1s5tRsOW8KCMe_ZDff2WeDDwkkUqRYUZuITuqTppDF60ppVy1lAMUo-8dtwF7y7DS7V2pUnsuyraTi9-yBh1Ph9QvzrZjFjFd2EAxset1jRkUq_tmVeDycWykNzOJQExwCSujBf4bxf1cPQv2Fu1) seems to be well defined. But after rendering I don't find the rendered image any comprehensible.

I have asked for the `company services` to be rendered to the bottom but they are rendered to the right. Next `Bolum System` had to be rendered on left but its drawn on right.

Can someone help me fix this diagram so it's easily comprehensible/understandable.

Plantuml code is as below -

```
@startuml
!pragma layout smetana


!include <C4/C4_Container.puml>
!include <C4/C4_Component.puml>
HIDE_STEREOTYPE()
skinparam System_Ext {
    MinWidth 100
    MinHeight 50
}

AddSystemTag("retail-esl", $legendText="Physical Retail ESL")
AddExternalSystemTag("retail-owned", $bgColor="blue", $legendText="Retail Owned")
AddExternalSystemTag("internal", $bgColor="purple", $legendText="Company Owned")
AddExternalSystemTag("external", $bgColor="grey", $legendText="External Vendor")

Person(associate, "Associate", "Company employee working in a store.")

System_Boundary(retailEsl, "Retail ESL") {
    System(eslJobs, "ESL Jobs", $tags="esl-jobs")
    System(eslGateway, "ESL Gateway", $tags="esl-gateway")
    System(ahEsl, "AH - ESL", $tags="ah-esl")
    ComponentDb(db, "post-gres")
}

System(boluM, "BoluM System", $tags="external")

System_Boundary(companyServices, "company services") {
  System_Ext(catalog, "Catalog Service", " ", $tags="internal")
  System_Ext(pricing, "Pricing Service", " ", $tags="internal")
  System_Ext(liteship, "LiteShip Service", " ", $tags="internal")
  System_Ext(reviews, "Reviews Service", " ", $tags="internal")
  System_Ext(ahura, "Ahura Service", " ", $tags="internal")
  System_Ext(rainmaker, "Rainmaker service", " ", $tags="internal")
}

System_Boundary(retailServices, "retail services") {
  System_Ext(translation, "Transalation Service", " ", $tags="retail-owned")
  System_Ext(rsms, "RSMS", " ", $tags="retail-owned")
  System_Ext(ratt, "RATT", " ", $tags="retail-owned")
} 


Rel_D(associate, ahEsl, "Manage Self Labels") 
Rel_D(ahEsl, eslGateway, " ")

Rel_R(eslJobs, db, " ")
Rel_R(eslGateway, db, " ")

Rel_D(retailEsl, catalog, " ")
Rel_D(retailEsl, pricing, " ")
Rel_D(retailEsl, liteship, " ")
Rel_D(retailEsl, reviews, " ")
Rel_D(retailEsl, ahura, " ")
Rel_D(retailEsl, rainmaker, " ")

Rel_R(retailEsl, translation, " ")
Rel_R(retailEsl, rsms, " ")
Rel_R(retailEsl, ratt, " ")

Rel_L(retailEsl, boluM, " ")

SHOW_LEGEND(true)
@enduml
```